# How to recover usual Plug & Play function for one particular USB port on Windows 7 for storage devices?

Tags: windows-7, usb-storage, plug-and-play

When I plug in various Mass Storage Devices (usb drives, external HDD) to one particular USB port, does not trigger the usual Plug & Play functions. No sound is heard. The device shows up in the Explorer and **can be used as per normal** (i.e. the USB port is functioning, works in linux, etc).

However Windows does not launch autoplay nor does the "Safely remove hardware" detect it (icon does not show).

Plugging the same device into the other usb port works as per normal. Sound is played on plug-in and out, "safely remove hardware", autoplay shows, etc.

How do I recover the usual Plug & Play behavior for the former USB port?

I am using Win7 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

My initial reaction is that you have a fried USB port, particularly since it won't detect other devices. You can always try to run the native action center in Windows 7 (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/windows-troubleshooting), but it may very well be a problem with that port since the other one does work.

Comment: Perhaps the initial question was confusing. I will rephrase it. The port is not fried. It works. Just that Windows does not do the usual things it does at the start as with other USB ports, e.g. registering it as a device that can be "Safely Removed"